# Escaping and quickly pressing certain keys brings me back to insert mode

Tags: key-bindings

So I have quite some plug-ins installed and have set a lot of key combinations, and it seems like one of these key combinations makes me revert to insert mode, when I quickly press <kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>b</kbd> after pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>. It will still execute the command (<kbd>b</kbd> will take me back one word, <kbd>d</kbd> is the equivalent to <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> curiously enough).

How can I stop this behavior. I can't even imagine what Vim feature causes this behavior. After a second or so leaving insert mode, none of this applies any more. It is only possible in the short time span after leaving insert mode.

Can somebody tell what vim feature can cause this behavior and how to check for it?

Comment: Are you sure it's a `vim` behaviour? If you use `vim` through some terminal emulation, quick presses of Esc and another key could be interpreted as escape sequence, causing strange things to happen.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's actually `tmux`!

Comment: This helped me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/esc-key-causes-a-small-delay-in-terminal-due-to-its-alt-behavior

Comment: Glad I could help. I suggest you post this finding and link as an answer and accept it, so the question doesn't remain open